# Identify strings having words from two different lists

Tags: python, list, dataframe, nlp

I have a **dataframe** with three columns like this:

```
index   string                                         Result
1       The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 
2       fast and furious was a good movie
```

and i have **two lists** of words like this:

```
list1   ["over", "dog", "movie"]
list2   ["quick", "brown", "sun", "book"]
```

I want to identify strings that have at least one word from list1 **AND** at least one word from list2, such that the result will be as follows:

```
index   string                                      Result
1   The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog     TRUE
2   fast and furious was a good movie               FALSE
```

**Explanation**: The first sentence has words from both lists and so the result is TRUE. The second sentence has only one word from list1 and so it has a result of False.

Can we do that with python? I used search techniques from NLTK but i don't know how to combine results from the two lists. Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to check if the string has a word from one list? If you do, just combine both tests with `&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to split the strings and use `set.intersection` with `all` in a list comprehension:

```
s_lists = [set(list1), set(list2)]
df['Result'] = [all(s_lst.intersection(s.split()) for s_lst in s_lists) for s in df['string'].tolist()]
```

Output:

```
   index                                       string  Result
0      1  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog    True
1      2            fast and furious was a good movie   False
```

Comment: Can we go deeper like what are these words?

Comment: @Taie what do you mean? do you want to know the common words?

Comment: Yes please, that's what i meant, like saving them in a new column

Comment: @Taie see if `[[list(s_lst.intersection(s.split())) for s_lst in s_lists] for s in df['string'].tolist()]` works for you

Comment: great it works as expected. moreover, it gives me the words in separete groups (based on their original lists)

Answer (score 3):

If your dataframe (with the first two columns) is called `df`, you can do the following:

```
df['Result'] = (df['string'].str.contains('|'.join(list1)) 
 & df['string'].str.contains('|'.join(list2)))
```

The result:

```
                                        string  Result
0  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog    True
1            fast and furious was a good movie   False
```

---

In response to your comment, perhaps the following does what you want:

```
words = set(list1).union(set(list2))
df['Result_2'] = [[*words.intersection(s.split())] for s in df['string'].tolist()]
```

The result:

```
...   Result                   Result_2
...    True  [dog, quick, brown, over]
...   False                    [movie]
```

Comment: Can we go deeper like what are these words?

Comment: @Taie I've added something that addresses what I think you're asking for based on your comments on the other answer. See my edit.